# Fallo en dataset para gridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, vb.net, .net

Tengo un problema a la hora de guardar. En mi Site Master tengo un Timer que al hacer hacer el page_load se activa, una vez se activa y pasa el intervalo para hacer el Tick ejecuto el siguiente comando:

```
 If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SISTEMAConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Dim query As String = "SELECT TOP 1 Nombre, Grupo FROM USUARIO;"

            Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                    Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                        cmd.Connection = con
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                        Using ds As New DataSet()
                            sda.Fill(ds)
                            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                            GridView1.DataBind()
                            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(1)
                            GridView1.DataBind()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
```

El problema que tengo es que me da fallo al llegar a la línea de ds.Tables(0). Mi intención es recoger el valor de la casilla Nombre y Grupo para posteriormente guardarlo en una clase general del proyecto para poder utilizarla en distintas pantallas.

Me aparece el fallo: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de objeto

Comment: He podido volcar los datos en una variable de la misma clase, pero en un futuro si que necesitare volcar los datos en un gridview y después coger del gridview los valores. Antes trabaja en vb.net y usaba datagridview pero al cambiar a asp no consigo utilizarlo.